# Need 3 divs to be center aligned side by side

Tags: html, css

I need three buttons aligned side by side. float:left just floats the elements to the left (I want them center-aligned).

I have already specified display:inline block and vertical align:top

```css
div.rotateBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

div.randomBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

div.nextBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

.alignme {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alignme">

  <div class="rotateBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="flipCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="randomBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="randomiseCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="nextBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="nextCard()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4sgakgck/

Comment: u can use `<center>` tag

Comment: if this is a new project and you're not too far into it, you could bootstrap it; it's an option

Comment: @MandarSant you mean the `center` tag that has been deprecated for years?

Comment: @Turnip i didnt got what r u saying

Comment: I mean the `center` tag was deprecated years ago. i.e. You should not use it any more. It could be removed from browsers at any time.

Comment: @Turnip it is the easiest way and still works but any ways i still respect ur concern.

Comment: It works today. It may not tomorrow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @Turnip I think you meant "not" ;-) bit of a typo. Edit: ah edited.

Comment: Man, you are pedantic today O_0

Comment: @Turnip lol!  *"Dot the i's and cross the T's"* as the saying goes. Big difference between "now" and "not", wouldn't you agree? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `display:inline block` is on the wrong elements.

This should be all you need:

```
.alignme {
  text-align: center;
}

.alignme > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Example:

```css
div.rotateBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

div.randomBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

div.nextBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

.alignme {
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

.alignme > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="alignme">

  <div class="rotateBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="flipCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="randomBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="randomiseCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="nextBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="nextCard()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but for (much) smaller screens (resolution), that'll come out as 2 on top, 1 under them; *just saying*.

Comment: Well obviously. There was no mention of resizing elements to fit on mobile.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was "just saying" ;-) being a bit of a sidenote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox`.

```css
div.rotateBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}
div.randomBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}
div.nextBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}
.alignme {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alignme">
  <div class="rotateBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="flipCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="randomBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="randomiseCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="nextBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="nextCard()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works (also), but for (much) smaller screens (resolution), that'll come out as 2 on top, 1 under them; *just saying*.

Comment: You can use `flex-wrap: no-wrap` if you don't want them to jump another line while resizing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniek & Fred

Answer (score 0):

- List item

```css
div.rotateBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

div.randomBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

div.nextBtn input {
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
}

.alignme {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alignme">

  <div class="rotateBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="flipCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="randomBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="randomiseCard()">
  </div>
  <div class="nextBtn">
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="nextCard()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).